# PyQt frame which changes color with child focus

Tags: python, python-2.x, event-handling, qt, pyqt

I am working on an application that has various "panels" contained within splitters. I wanted the panel border to change color when one of it's children gained focus. Here is a simple example of the solution I came up with. I think it is pretty clean and quite scalable, but I wanted to see if there is anything I might be able to improve about it, or if there was a better convention for this. I'm still quite new to class instantiation and there's always a ton more to learn about Qt! In particular I want to make sure I'm using `super` correctly, and my implementation of event filters is efficient.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class BasePanel(QtGui.QWidget):
    """This is more or less abstract, subclass it for 'panels' in the main UI"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BasePanel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.frame_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.frame_layout)

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.frame.setObjectName("base_frame")
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Box | QtGui.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frame.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frame_layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.base_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.base_layout)

        self.focus_in_color = "rgb(50, 255, 150)"
        self.focus_out_color = "rgb(100, 100, 100)"
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("#base_frame {border: 1px solid %s}" % self.focus_out_color)
        self.installEventFilter(self) # this will catch focus events'

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            self.frame.setStyleSheet("#base_frame {border: 1px solid %s}" % self.focus_in_color)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            self.frame.setStyleSheet("#base_frame {border: 1px solid %s}" % self.focus_out_color)
        return False # passes this event to the child, i.e. does not block it from the child widgets

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(BasePanel, self).showEvent(event)
        # this will isntal the focus in/out event filter in all children of the panel
        for widget in self.findChildren(QtGui.QWidget):
            widget.installEventFilter(self)


class LeftPanel(BasePanel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LeftPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        title = QtGui.QLabel("Left Panel")
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.base_layout.addWidget(title)

        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.base_layout.addWidget(edit)


class RightPanel(BasePanel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RightPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        title = QtGui.QLabel("Right Panel")
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.base_layout.addWidget(title)

        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.base_layout.addWidget(edit)

class MainApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__()

        main_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        left_panel = LeftPanel()
        main_layout.addWidget(left_panel)

        right_panel = RightPanel()
        main_layout.addWidget(right_panel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApp()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```